# WebRTC for iOS drops frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc

I've compiled a WebRTC.framework recently on macOS Sierra for iOS from 
[here](https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/). Replaced old framework with new one in existing xcode project an video become Very Very slow with following error:

`(RTCLogging.mm:31): 
(RTCCameraVideoCapturer.m:207 -
[RTCCameraVideoCapturer captureOutput:didDropSampleBuffer:fromConnection:]): Dropped sample buffer.`

`(frame_buffer2.cc:208): A frame about to be decoded is out of the configured delay bounds (16067 > 10000). Resetting the video jitter buffer.`

Any Ideas what can cause the issue?

Thanks.